# How to get function argument list and return value (type and value) by r2 or r2pipe, static disassembling and dynamic debugging?

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, disassembly, radare2

When disassemble a program (Intel, arm with format elf or exe , etc) , I need to print each function's argument. Now I am working on radare 2 with r2pipe. How can I get a function's argument list (both number and type) ? Or can I get argument list by IDA script?

What's more, when debugging a program using r2, how can I get the value of each argument and return value with r2pipe?  for int, char *, etc.